# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSArray' to 'NSString'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, nsstring

The RecipeBookViewController.m file is showing a warning in Xcode "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSArray' to 'NSString'

can anyone fix this warning.

I am developing RecipeBook application from appcoda website from tutorial Tutorial #14

Here is my Recipe.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Recipe : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *prepTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageFile;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ingredients;

@end
```

Here is my Recipe.m file

```
#import "Recipe.h"

@implementation Recipe
@synthesize name,prepTime,imageFile,ingredients;

@end
```

Here is my RecipeBookViewController.m file

```
#import "RecipeBookViewController.h"
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"

@interface RecipeBookViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipeBookViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    //recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

    Recipe *recipe1 = [Recipe new];
    recipe1.name = @"Egg Benedict";
    recipe1.prepTime = @"30 min";
    recipe1.imageFile = @"egg_benedict.jpg";
    recipe1.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2 fresh English muffins", @"4 eggs", @"4 rashers of back bacon", @"2 egg yolks", @"1 tbsp of lemon juice", @"125 g of butter", @"salt and pepper", nil];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that ingredients is an `NSString`, i.e.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ingredients;
```

But, as the error states, you're trying to assign an array to the `NSString`, i.e.

```
recipe1.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2 fresh English muffins", @"4 eggs",...
```

So you can change ingredients to an `NSArray` to correct this error, ex:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *ingredients;
```

Comment: Thank you Lyndsey Scott. you fix it

Answer (score 1):

ingredients is of class nsstring....change it to Nsarry.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *ingredients;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `recipe1.ingredients` is `NSString` type that's why you are getting this warning so please change it to `NSArray` type.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *ingredients;
```